# Api Facebook live streaming

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-sdk, streaming

Alguem já precisou pegar uma Lista de países para enviar um POST com Geoblock utilizando a API do facebook para ligar uma live? estou ligando os meus lives por um serviço, agora preciso determinar por ele os paises que podem ver o meu streaming e os que não podem, da mesma forma que conseguimos fazer pelo ADM do face que nem está na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]